# Converting XML to XSD using XSDGen

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

Hi I am converting the xml file to XSD file by using XSDGen(org.wiztools.xsdgen.XsdGen)

```
    **XsdGen xsdGen  = null;

        try {

            xsdGen = new XsdGen();

            log("xsdGen After :: " + xsdGen);

            xsdGen.parse(file);**
```

But I am getting error as below:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wiztools.xsdgen.XsdGen.toString(XsdGen.java:179)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
```

Comment: The XsdGen.java :179 is
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return doc.toXML();
    }

Comment: Does the XML that you are using for this exist, is it at the right location, and is it a valid XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I find out the root cause. Actually the server is using openJDK rather than oracle jdk.